# Minimum Euclidean distance path between multi-dimensional points

Tags: python, scipy, graph-theory, hierarchical-clustering

I have  a set of 5-dimensional vectors. I need to order them such that the path taken by iterating over the list minimises the total euclidean distance between each vector.

I have played with scipy.sparse.csgraph.minimum_spanning_tree
and scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage but have not been successful so far

For example if I have a 10 x 5 array, where each row corresponds to a point in 5 dimensional space. How do I reorder the rows such that travelling from top to bottom of the array results in the minimum total Euclidean distance travelled.

I feel this must be a well defined problem but my research has not led me anywhere conclusive. It seems to me that a solution would incorporate graph theory - a minimum spanning tree. I'd be very grateful for any suggestions.

Is there an existing library that can do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Scipy also has a function for a [minimum spanning tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.minimum_spanning_tree.html)